# Which function will be selected?

Tags: c

I have a doubt.. it was question in my quiz.. Like to know the answer for this question.

```
Question: 

int foo(int);
double foo(int);
double foo(double);

void bar(int value){
double score = foo(value);
}
```

which of the function declarations will be selected? or it is none of the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C doesn't support overloading (functions with the same name).

If this is really a C++ question, C++ doesn't allow overloads where only the return type is different (`int foo(int)` and `double foo(int)`).

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do it in C.If anyone can able to implement it then it will be the biggest breakthrough in Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support overloading. You cannot have multiple functions with the same name.

Your code will not compile, and thus the question about how it behaves is undefined.

This is why, for instance, the math library provides both `sin()` that works on `double`, and `sinf()` that uses single-precision `float` values instead.